# How do I determine the most popular version of a given npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

The `npm` registry provides metrics on the [most depended packages](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended), but say you wanted to determine the most popular version of a given package - is that possible?

As a user, say I'm thinking of upgrading to `react-router^4.0.0`, but would like to look at some adoption numbers (i.e. the number of folks running `^3.0.0` vs `^4.0.0`), is there a way to do this? Generically, say a given package has 500k downloads in the past month, I couldn't imagine they are all for `foobar@latest`, so looking at a breakdown of downloads per version would seem to be useful.

Moreover, as a publisher, say I have some packages published to `npm` and would like to understand which versions of these packages are the most popular with my users. Does `npm` offer some type of report for this? I can't seem to find these number when I'm logged in and viewing my published items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NPM exposes now a number of downloads per version.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript -> click "versions"

Comment: Nice, looks like they added this since 2018.

Comment: I think it was just a few weeks ago - not sure. Anyway, please consider changing the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 5):

This might not be the answer you are looking for but unfortunately it doesn't seem like that's possible. You do have a way to see total downloads and there are sites like [npm-stat](https://npm-stat.com/) to show a breakdown of when downloads are happening. You might be able to infer from when releases happen for specific packages to get an idea of how many downloads that version has.

It's worth mentioning [npm's article on how download counts work](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/92574016600/numeric-precision-matters-how-npm-download-counts-work.html) though so you can't say download counts == number of people who did `npm install`

Another, although rather extreme, option is you could try and search for [JSON files that have the react-router](https://github.com/search?l=&p=1&q=%22react-router%22%3A+%22%5E4.0.0%22+extension%3Ajson&ref=advsearch&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) and see the dependencies. I was hoping to see if Github or [SearchCode](https://searchcode.com/) had filtering options for you to specify it but it only has so many filters. You could probably automate this though but naturally it would still not be very accurate.

Also worth mentioning there is an [open issue regarding instrumenting analytics into npm CLI](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6904)

Comment: I can't seem to hit npm-stat anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be really nice if there are such statistics provided by NPM. But unfortunately there aren't any such statistics available at the moment.

NPM only provides total downloads in the last month. If you want to see total downloads over a larger period of time you can use **[npm-stat](https://npm-stat.com)**. But also it doesn't give download status specific to each version.

Usually `npm install --save <package-name>` installs the latest version available at the moment, which is locked to the package.json file. If u want to upgrade to the advanced version later, currently the best way is to follow the upgrade instruction provided by the package's documentation or seek support from the developers of the package to check if the upgrade is worth your time.

Comment: I can't seem to hit npm-stat anymore.