# 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'Link'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router@4.1.1

```
└─┬ react-router@4.1.1
  ├─┬ history@4.6.1
  │ ├── resolve-pathname@2.1.0
  │ └── value-equal@0.2.1
  └── warning@3.0.0
```

and this message appears in development when attaching a react-router Link

```
./src/containers/FilterLink.js
37:4-8 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'Link'.
```

This is the import code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
```

By the way changing version to react-router@2.0.1 seems to be working.
Does anyone know if Link was removed from react-router? what happened with Link?

If not, why do I get this error?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

4.x introduced some breaking changes, you'll need to import `Link` from `react-router-dom`:

**CommonJS**

```
var Link = require('react-router-dom').Link
```

**ES6 Modules**

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Take a peek here for some additional background: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom

Comment: does it provide any side effect when combined with browserHistory from react-router?

Comment: @Karlos If you do something like `<Link to={browserHistory.push('/foo')}>`, that will most likely have to change. They really did completely rewrite 4.x - have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4

Comment: I see router 4.x breaks rendering flow with react-dom render, even if using Router, Route from react-router-dom. I would like to minimize the refactoring of the code for this change, so decide whether to use 4.x with compatible versions of react-dom or just keep using react-router < 4.x

Comment: @Karlos To be honest, the refactoring from 2/3.x to 4.x was just too much of a burden. I'm currently sticking with 3.x on all my projects, I just don't like the 4.x API at all.

Comment: @Karlos If npm allowed us to dig into which versions of a project get downloaded the most, that would be valuable, since I'm assuming most folks are sticking it out on 3.x as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406069/determine-most-popular-version-of-a-given-npm-package

Comment: I see, I do prefer previous versions of react-router too. I will use a good version of 3.x and force any future react-router package.json deps to be 3.x

Comment: @Karlos Clicked the chat by accident, feel free to disregard. And I think that's a safe call, AFAIK, they will be supporting 3.x indefinitely, so upgrading to 4.x is not at all required.

Comment: Following a tutorial that's less than a year old and I'm having to set my version to 3 as well.

Comment: Don't forget to install the `react-router-dom` package instead of `react-router`: `npm install --save react-router-dom`